# Ruby run function calling each item in file

Tags: ruby, string

I am currently playing with ruby and have come up with the following

```
require 'simple_youtube'

def video_search(term, maxresults, file)
  video_search = Youtube::Video.find(:params => {:q => "#{term}", :"max-results" => "#{maxresults}", :v => '2'})
  min = 0                                                           # => setting min variable = 0
  max = video_search.entry.size                                 # => setting max to #{maxresults}
  while min < max do
    export_results(file,video_search.entry[min].link[0].href)   # => outputs each of the results to the listed file
    min +=1
  end
  run = exec("~/Scripts/BASH/./music.sh #{file}")                   #=> Automatically downloads the items
end

def export_results(file, item)
  open(file, 'a') do |f|
    f.puts "#{item}\n"
  end
end

video_search(ARGV[0],ARGV[1],ARGV[2])                   # => Call the search with arguments
                                                        # => ARGV[0] - #{term}
                                                        # => ARGV[1] - #{maxresults}
                                                        # => ARGV[2] - #{file}
```

What I would like to do now is have a file of search terms and call the video_search with each item in the file

```
file='/users/Ondrovic/Desktop/music.txt'
  f = File.open(file, "r")
  f.each_line { |line|
    puts line
  }
  f.close
```

The above I can read each line just not sure how to incorporate the two properly.

/users/Ondrovic/Desktop/music.txt would contain something like the following

```
 Trapt Trapt
 Godsmack Shine Down
 etc
```

Then read each of them from the file and run the search

Comment: What is your question and what are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: @User089247 want to feed in a text file with search terms to the video_search function

Comment: What's with data in `Test.txt` and what's in `/users/Ondrovic/Desktop/music.txt` file?

Comment: so the data in /users/Ondrovic/Desktop/music.txt would be the terms I want to search for, so I just need to feed each item into the video_search function

Comment: You should really fix the code indentation. https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: This is not a best practice since Ruby is all about OO programming.

But, here is how you can stitch your code to make it work:

```
require 'simple_youtube'

def video_search(term, maxresults, file) 
  video_search = Youtube::Video.find(:params => {:q => "#{term}", :"max-results" => "#{maxresults}", :v => '2'})
  min = 0                                                         # => setting min variable = 0
  max = video_search.entry.size                                   # => setting max to #{maxresults}
  while min < max do
    export_results(file,video_search.entry[min].link[0].href)   # => outputs each of the results to the listed file
    min +=1
  end

  run = exec("~/Scripts/BASH/./music.sh #{file}")                 #=> Automatically downloads the items
end

def export_results(file, item)
  open(file, 'a') do |f|
    f.puts "#{item}\n"
  end
end

# => Call the search with arguments
# => line    - term
# => ARGV[0] - maxresults
# => ARGV[1] - file
file = '/users/Ondrovic/Desktop/music.txt' # or your can use `ARGV[0]` for term's file path
maxresults = ARGV[0] || 10
if ARGV[1]
  f = File.open(file, "r")
  f.each_line { |line| video_search(line, maxresults, ARGV[1]) }
  f.close
else
  puts 'Please provide two arguments: first as maxresults and second the file path'
end
```

Comment: what would be the best practice?

Comment: Note that you can always use Ruby in a functional programming style. But since Ruby is a pure object-oriented programming language. I'd encourage you to create a class and define attributes instead of arguments, instantiate object of class and pass those arguments as attributes while initializing the objects and doing the iteration. However, the above code should have worked, right? Please don't forget to accept answer of your question on SO if they solves your problem. Have a happy programming.